# Newton’s method on functions that contains matrices using Python

Tags: python, newtons-method

I was able to find several implementations of Newton's methods, for example, [this link](https://www.math.ubc.ca/~pwalls/math-python/roots-optimization/newton/) or [maybe this one](http://hplgit.github.io/Programming-for-Computations/pub/p4c/._p4c-bootstrap-Python027.html).

However, most of the time the examples are with simple functions such as:
 x^2−9=0 or x^3-x^2-1=0. I am looking for something that would work for:
[image]

My question for that I am lost in how to use this code to solve my problem. For example, I am not sure how I would apply the derivative (dfdx) on my F(x) that contain matrices. Also, if I should direct input the matrices on my "def f(x)"

The code that I am using:

```
def Newton(f, dfdx, x, eps):
    f_value = f(x)
    iteration_counter = 0
    while abs(f_value) > eps and iteration_counter < 100:
        try:
            x = x - float(f_value)/dfdx(x)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
            print "Error! - derivative zero for x = ", x
            sys.exit(1)     # Abort with error

        f_value = f(x)
        iteration_counter += 1

    # Here, either a solution is found, or too many iterations
    if abs(f_value) > eps:
        iteration_counter = -1
    return x, iteration_counter

def f(x):
    return x**2 - 9

def dfdx(x):
    return 2*x

solution, no_iterations = Newton(f, dfdx, x=1000, eps=1.0e-6)

if no_iterations > 0:    # Solution found
    print "Number of function calls: %d" % (1 + 2*no_iterations)
    print "A solution is: %f" % (solution)
else:
    print "Solution not found!"
```

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `neural-network` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

There aren't any special rules for deriving matrices - the derivative is just calculated for each element separately. I would suggest evaluating the $[x1,x2]' * M * [x1,x2]$ expression on paper to get a matrix of polynomials, and then calculating the derivative of each one.